# Is there a way to program alexa to read html text from a page specified by saying "Alexa, What is server status?"?

Tags: html, alexa-skills-kit

I am having trouble finding a way to perform a simple operation without making it way more complex than it has to be.

Example: I want to say "Alexa, What is the status of my website?"
I want it to know I'm referring to http://refindustry.com/index1.php
And I want it to read the single line on that page that at current says"Our website is under construction"

It is a really simple operation each time I want it to request the defined page and read the single line of html text on the page.

Keep in mind I don't want to have to host a server or pay amazon to do this I just want her to simply request the page and read the single line.

Tried going to amazon developer and it looked insane account linking lamda requests just way more difficult that it should be.

Comment: So what have you tried? AI understanding your custom command and reading custom page may be difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the free tier of AWS to host a lambda that can fetch the text from your website and return the response to Alexa.
Then you need to setup your skill with a few sample utterances for how to ask for the status of your website and use this lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a service that will fulfil the intent from Alexa - this could be a server somewhere (so the skill would send the request via HTTP), or a Lambda function.

As Josep says, you can get a free AWS tier - write some code to fetch the page and "grab" the status, before using it in the response to Alexa. It should be pretty straight forward to do this.

If you're a little daunted about AWS, you could look at Hosted Skills - https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/ebc1c777-2cb2-4210-8c89-2a70dd1a0248/get-your-head-out-of-the-cloud-with-alexa-hosted-skills-preview